# Kalachakra Tantra (translation of the original text)

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, tantra

Where can I find the English / Chinese translation of the Kalachakra Tantra? (not commentary) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalachakra#cite_note-9) suggests you might be looking for "[Kilty, G: *Ornament of Stainless Light*, Wisdom 2004](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kilty%2C+G+Ornament+of+Stainless+Light%2C+Wisdom+2004)".